# C Warning: statement with no effect with bitwise operations

Tags: c

When I try to compile my code, I am getting a c statement with no effect warning:

I am trying to use the bitwise operation to shift a value to the left. This is the code I am trying to do:

```
*bits << 5
```

bits is a unsigned pointer.

Comment: `* bits <<= 5;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calculating a value, but not assigning it to anything.

You probably want to do this instead:

```
*bits <<= 5;
// or equivalent
*bits = *bits << 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to alter the value of `*bits`, you need to do a variable assignment.  I.e.,

```
*bits = (*bits <<  5);
```